# How to echo out information from mongodb with node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

in PHP it's very easy to echo out information from a MySql-database and encapsulate the result with html-attributes in a query like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM files ORDER BY ID DESC";
        $response = mysql_query($query);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($response))  
              echo '<img src="'.$row["image"].'" alt="..." />';
```

How would i go about doing something similar in node js from a MongoDB server?
My collection looks like this:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("59106cc31bcace320c33a9d3"),
"path" : "uploads/bicycle.jpg",
"originalname" : "bicycle.jpg",
"__v" : 0
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Node.js is not PHP and one can only be glad that this is the case.

Comment: Still, there surely must be a way to accomplish what i'm looking for? if not, there is not much to be glad about :)

Comment: It doesn't look like you've tried anything... A simple search for node and mongo gets lots of results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so node works differently, node js will have a different js altogether running at server, not some embedded code in the html files.

Of course, you can accomplish what you want like this

-Get mysql package from https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql
-Get mongoose package for mongoDB (quite reliable and widely used) from https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose

and then your node js file like this

```
var express = require("express");

var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'web',
  password: '',
  database: 'my_database'
});
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var app = express();

app.get("/getmyimg", function(req, res) {
  connection.query("SELECT * FROM files ORDER BY ID DESC", (err, rows) => {
    for (let row of rows) {
      resp.send('<img src="' + row["image"] + '" alt="..." />')
    }
  })
})
var CollectionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        path: String,
        original_name: String
    });

CollectionName = mongoose.model('CollectionName',CollectionSchema);

app.get("/getmyimgmongo", function(req, res) {
  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/my_database1');
  collectionName.find({}, (err, results) =>{
    for (let row of results) {
      resp.send('<img src="' + row["image"] + '" alt="..." />')
    }
  })
})

app.listen(4200, function() {
  console.log("Listening to port 4200");
});
```

Now just you can load localhost:4200/getmyimg and your task is accomplished

Comment: Thank you Sir! Exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: Edit: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined. When i try to access /getmyimgmongo it gives me a bunch of errors. `collectionName is not defined`. how would i define that? my collection is called `files` any ideas?

Comment: Oh yes forgot to mention you have to create your schema to be able to access that collection in mongoose, updated the answer.

Comment: Still can't get it to show on my end unfortunately. /getmyimgmongo doesn't load. it just keeps trying to load. Any ideas? please check https://github.com/joelfolkesson/myapp/blob/master/imagefile.js

Answer (score -1):

In order to achieve this you would make a HTTP request to the mongo db server. This is explained here:

https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/#http-interfaces

The server will return a JSON response containing the data required within its body. Using JavaScript client side you could then append a child referencing the value of the key path.

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = response.path;
document.getElementById("page").appendChild(img);
```

Hope this is some help.